# SQL - How to check overflow of data type

Tags: sql, overflow

I would like to check for an overflow of a specific data type of column in SQL database. Here is the text that I need put into my SQL:

> "overflow happened when the value is out of the interval of a column's data
>   type"

Comment: What database & what are you doing that can cause an overflow

Comment: For int? datetime? length of text?

Comment: Use try catch statement in stored procedure

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would work for SQL Server...

```
DECLARE @userInput NVarChar(100) = '129387918279387987123123';
DECLARE @value Int;

BEGIN TRY
  SELECT @value = CONVERT(Int, @userInput);
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  PRINT 'Overflow happend when the value is out of interval of column''s data type';
END CATCH;
```

Answer (score 1):

In a database application, there isn't really any good way to recover automatically (to recover in code) from overflow. You have to rollback the transaction.

So you're going to have to trap the overflow error the server raises, and then either rollback or raise that error again so some other module can rollback. I really don't see the point in doing that, but I might be missing something.

Am I missing something?

Comment: this is solution in our script, but I really do not understand to it. I am novice in this.

Comment: from data_stage_tmp.gc_currency_quotes
  where abs(spot_ask) >= cast (99999.9999999 as decimal (13, 7));

Comment: I need to feed some table from another table with check overflow fields and delete rows with it before I feed that table